# Scroll no funciona correctamente después de mostrar un listado con Ajax Jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scroll, animate.css

Tengo un listado donde figuran varios `items` cada uno dentro de su propio `div` identificado con un `id="Publicacion-1", "Publicacion-2", "Publicacion-3"` (el numero es el `id del item`) sucesivamente y cada div, con un botón de Editar, una vez que aprieto el botón, hago una edición, se cierra el modal y ejecuto una función que muestra nuevamente el listado. La idea es que la pantalla me muestre en el renglón que modifique. Que lo posicione donde estaba. Para lo cual, cree una `funcion` que recibe entre otros, dos parámetros llamado `aTipo` y  `aFoco`,:

```
function listar(aTipo,aFoco){
     var Enfocando = aFoco;   
     $.ajax({
       url:='../phpAux/ListadoBusquedasEmpresas.php',
       type:'POST',
       data:'Tipo=' +aTipo,
       beforeSend: function () {
        $('.ZonaListados').html('<h5><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw">
         </i>Procesando Listado...</h5>"');
        },            
       success: function (data) {    
         $('.ContieneBusquedas').show();               
         $(".ZonaListados").html(data);
         $(document).ready(function(){          
          console.log("Foco en :#Publicacion-"+Enfocando); //acá me muestra el valor perfecto
               $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $("#Publicacion-"+Enfocando).offset().top
                }, 500);
            })   
         }  
     })  
}
```

La función lista perfectamente, enviando la Variable `aTipo`, pero cuando muestra el listado, la función de `scroll` se mueve siempre a 6 u 8 `divs` del correcto. 
Estoy haciendo algo mal?
 (Yo coloque un console.log que me muestra que el valor del item para posicionarse llega bien y es el correcto.)

Comment: ¿6 u 8 divs, arriba o abajo? Si es arriba y el final de la página está visible, entonces no puedes hacer más scroll, porque ya no hay más contenido para bajar. En todo caso, lo que podrías hacer es animar el div, probablemente con `fadeOut()` y luego con `fadeIn()` para identificar lo que se actualizó.

Comment: Son 6 u ocho divs hacia abajo, o sea se pasa...

Comment: No entendí el resto de tu respuesta Triby, sobre lo del fadeOut() y fadeIn()

Comment: No te preocupes, no tiene sentido si el elemento no está a la vista. Ahora, la cosa está un poco complicada y necesitamos una forma de reproducir tu problema para poder sugerirte soluciones, el código en tu pregunta no es suficiente.

Comment: Gracias Triby por tu aporte, no sé que mas poner, creo que describí detalladamente el problema, ademas como los controles del `console.log` que puse me demuestra que el indicador del `Id` del `div` que debe ubicarse es el correcto, de hecho se acerca... Se que algunos hay tenido problemas con el `scroll`, tal vez haya otra forma de hacerlo.